# Can I use Python asyncio to slice and save DataFrame in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-asyncio

As the title says - is it possible to write an asyncio event loop that will slice DataFrame by unique values in a certain column and save it on my drive? And maybe more importantly - is it faster?

What I've tried is something like this:

```
async def a_split(dist,df):
    temp_df = df[df.district == dist]
    await temp_df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(d))

async def m_lp(df):
    for dist in df.district.unique().tolist():
        await async_slice(dist,df)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(m_lp(dfTotal))  
loop.close()
```

But I'm getting a following error:

```
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

If it's not obvious from my attempt, I'm very new to asyncio and I'm not sure how it works. Apologies if this is a stupid question.

If asyncio is not a good tool for the job - is there a better one?

Edit:

Full traceback below:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-2bc2373d2920> in <module>()
      2 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      3 
----> 4 loop.run_until_complete(m_lp(dfTotal))
      5 loop.close()

C:\Users\5157213\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py in run_until_complete(self, future)
    464             raise RuntimeError('Event loop stopped before Future completed.')
    465 
--> 466         return future.result()
    467 
    468     def stop(self):

<ipython-input-20-9e91c0b1b06f> in m_lp(df)
      1 async def m_lp(df):
      2     for dist in df.district.unique().tolist():
----> 3         await a_split(dist,df)

<ipython-input-18-200b08417159> in a_split(dist, df)
      1 async def a_split(dist,df):
      2     temp = df[df.district == dist]
----> 3     await temp.to_csv('C:/Users/5157213/Desktop/Portfolio/{}.csv'.format(dist))

TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45154096/edit) the question to include the full traceback. As it stands we can't tell which `await` that refers to.

Comment: Edited - it looks like it refers to the await next to df.to_csv line, but neither of the await's return anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no asyncio support as such in Pandas. I think the single-threaded event-based architecture is not the best tool in the systems where you have a dozens of other options to work with load/large data ie. for a large dataset take a look on [`dask`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/use-cases.html).

The error you get is because you tried to `await` function `Dataframe.to_csv` that does not return `Future` (or any other awaitable object), but the `None`.